# What are "encrypted instruction sets"?

Tags: encryption

In 1999, a news article ([Careless mistake reveals subversion of Windows by NSA](https://programmed-assassin.org/2017/10/02/windows/)) discussed "encrypted instruction sets". What exactly are these? Please provide a link so I can find more information.

Does it have anything to do with the following:

[A First Practical Fully Homomorphic Crypto-Processor Design](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.05278)

[Next-Generation Secure Computing Base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next-Generation_Secure_Computing_Base)

A similar question was asked here some time back ([What are 'Encrypted Instruction Sets' ?](https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/what-are-encrypted-instruction-sets.2311042/)), but it did not garner any useful responses.

I am already aware of hardware-based encryption & Intel's native support for AES. This one seems very different from the others.

Comment: Update: I had shot an email over to renowned cryptography expert Bruce Schneier who was kind enough to give a reply. Turns out he was the one to bring this issue up in 1999(https://imgur.com/a/FjN8o)

Comment: I believe that I have developed a novel machine learning algorithm for vision and locomotion that is way more efficient than the state-of-the-art reinforcement learning models out there today and was looking for ways to protect it from being reverse engineered by making it crypto-safe. Not just the code but also instructions at the processor level. Did not care to mention this in the question because that might perhaps be off-topic.

Answer (score -3):

i guess that encrypted instruction set is an encrypted instruction commands for cpu that will only work for encrypted programs.you can steal the program but can't execute it on your normal computer,or you can't hack to that computer because that computer can't run normal standard program unless it switch to normal instruction or translate the program.

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography StackExchange! It appears that your first answer wasn't all that well received, as it essentially is a wild guess without any reference to actual research defining "encrypted instruction sets" that way. Please [edit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/55555/edit) your answer to include such research and I'm sure it will be much more well-received :)